# How to prefer fully qualified "using name" at nested scope in .editorconfig for CSharp editor

Tags: c#, resharper, using, editorconfig, fully-qualified-naming

I want my Visual Studio #CS editor to prefer using fully qualified naming at using statements.
So i prefer:

```
using myproject.management.control.common;
```

rather than

```
using control.common;
```

There is such an option in Resharper "Prefer fully qualified using name at nested scope".

**what is the parallel setting for this in the .editorconfig file?**

Comment: Doesn't that depend on how you name the project and its hierarchy (default), or whatever namespace you decide to use within your project?

Comment: thanks for your comment. i found the answer . See my answer below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the flag in .editorconfig is as follows:

```
csharp_qualified_using_at_nested_scope = true
```

just set this to *true*

See: [Rider / Code style and cleanup / Use EditorConfig / EditorConfig properties](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/EditorConfig_Index.html)

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/EditorConfig_Index.html